# Mouse usage pictograms

Tags: icons

Is there a set of standard pictograms to explain using the mouse to navigate the interface? I would like to have icons for *dragging an object*, *scrolling the mouse wheel above the object* and similar. Are there some free pictograms available for such actions?

See example below:

[image: Mouse interaction pictograms]

Answer (score 4):

Let's be precise. I'm assuming that what you really want is not to explain how to use the mouse but to give some feedback to user on what he can do with the mouse cursor. The difference matters because it is important to know if you need some visuals with the whole mouse represented with a hand and some arrows to indicates moves (for an infographic for instance) or if you simply need some mouse cursor icon sets like this:

[image: Standard Mouse Cursors for Internet Browsers]

Comment: No, I am really looking for a standard way/free pictograms to explain how to use the mouse _to achieve something_. I've edited my question including an illustration to better clarify what I am after.

Comment: At least, my answer did help clarifying the question :)